# Changing relationships between tables using EF6 migrations

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, c#-5.0

Is it possible to change relationships between tables in EF6 without losing data? From my research, my understanding is that many-to-many relationships can be configured using the Fluent API in the onModelCreating method.

What wasn't clear was whether I would be able to change a table from a one-to-many relationship to a many-to-many relationship with a junction table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an explicit migration operation to move the data around like that, what you do is:

1. Alter your model as desired, either through the fluent API, POCO objects or designer.
2. In the `Up` method of the generated migration class, use the [DbMigration.Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method to move the data around in beween the generated Create/Add and Drop statements. Yes, this does involve manually writing the required SQL statements.